# Update hidden field value with array each time new item is added

Tags: jquery, arrays, onchange, var, hidden-field

How do update the hidden input field value with value of the variable `barrel` each time a new biscuit is added to the barrel?

So when multiple biscuits are added the field value could read `hobnob, Gingernut, Oreo`

jQuery...

```
var barrel_items = [];
var barrel = barrel_items;

$('[data-biscuit]').click(function(){
    var biscuit = $(this).data('biscuit');
    add_to_barrel(biscuit);
});


function add_to_barrel(item){

    var name = '';
    switch(item){
        case 'custardcream':
            name = 'Custard Creams';
            break;

        case 'jammydodger':
            name = 'Jammy Dodgers';
            break;
        case 'bourbon':
            name = 'Bourbons';
            break;
        case 'nice':
            name = 'Nice';
            break;
        case 'chocolatedigestive':
            name = 'Chocolate Digestives';
            break;
        case 'digestive':
            name = 'Digestive';
            break;
        case 'fruitshortcake':
            name = 'Fruit Shortcake';
            break;
        case 'gingernut':
            name = 'Gingernut';
            break;
        case 'oreo':
            name = 'Oreo';
            break;
        case 'hobnob':
            name = 'Hobnobs';
            break;
        case 'cookie':
            name = 'Cookies';
            break;


    }

    // If item is already there in array, it's index will be returned,
    // otherwise indexOf() will return -1
    var indexOfItem = barrel_items.indexOf(item);
    if(indexOfItem !== -1)
    {
        $('.barrel .chosen').eq(indexOfItem).remove();
        barrel_items.splice(indexOfItem,1);
    }
    else
    {
        $('.barrel').append('<div class="chosen">' + name + '</div>');
        barrel_items.push(item);
        //alert(barrel);

    }

    if ( barrel.length ) {
        $('.form').addClass( "show");
    } else if (!barrel.length) {
        $('.form').removeClass( "show");
    }

}
```

html...

```
<input type="hidden" id="barrel" name="barrel" value="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple as this:

```
$('[data-biscuit]').click(function(){
    var biscuit = $(this).data('biscuit');
    add_to_barrel(biscuit);
    $("#barrel").val(biscuit); //Add biscuit to barrel hidden input
});
```

Comment: ahh thanks it doesn't quite do what i want, your code changes the value of the hidden field, i need it to add and take away more than one value. so the hidden field could contain `cookie, custard cream, hobnob`.

Comment: then you can do this way - >`$("#barrel").val($("#barrel").val() + biscuit);`